# How to get entity(OneToMany) field in twig

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have to entity whohas reletionship OneToMany and ManyToOne and I find developer who have refernce and put intwig and I dont know how to visible reference intwig?
I have entity

```
/**
 * Developers
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="developers")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\CustomerBundle\Entity\Repository\DevelopersRepository")
 */
 class Developers extends SUser
 {
 /**
* @var integer
*
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
protected $id;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CodeUserReference", mappedBy="developer", cascade={"persist"})
*/
protected $reference_developer;
```

And entity with refernce

```
/**
* Coders 24 users
*
* @ORM\Table(name="code_user_reference")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeUserReferenceRepository")
*/
class CodeUserReference
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Developer", inversedBy="reference_developer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_talnet_file", nullable = true, referencedColumnName="id")
 * */
protected $developer;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $codereference;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $created_at;
```

Action:

```
        $dev_actual_with_ref = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer')
        ->getSelfAddedDevelopersR($role);
        $dev_actual_with_ref_number = count($dev_actual_with_ref);
```

and function

```
    public function getSelfAddedDevelopersR($role)
{


    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');

    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer', 'd')
        ->leftJoin('d.reference_developer', 'm')
        ->where('m.codereference IS NOT NULL')
        ->andwhere('d.roles = :role')
        ->setParameter('role', $role)
        ->getQuery();
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;

}
```

now twig

```
<span class="caption-subject font-green bold uppercase">dev_actual: <b>{{ dev_actual_with_ref_number }}</b></span>
{% for devs_actual in dev_actual_with_ref %}
<li>deveoper username: <b>{{ devs_actual.username }}</b></li>
<a href="{{ path('artel_admin_index', {'id': devs_actual.id, 'ida': developer.id}) }}"><b>Edit personal information</b></a>
<li>edit_personal_information: <a href="{{ path('artel_admin_index', {'id': devs_actual.id, 'ida': developer.id}) }}"><b>{{ devs_actual.username }}</b></a></li>


<a href="{{ path('artel_admin_index', {'id': devs_actual.id, 'ida': developer.id}) }}"><b>edit professional_skills</b></a>

<li>main_skills: <a href="{{ path('artel_admin_index', {'id': devs_actual.id, 'ida': developer.id}) }}"><b>{{ devs_actual.mainskill }}</b></a></li>

{% for skills in devs_actual.skills %}
    <ul>
    <li>{{ skills }}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
<li>reference: {{ devs_actual.reference_developer.codereference ???? }}</li>
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

now I have

```
Method "reference_developer" for object "Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer" does not exist in ArtelProfileBundle:Dachboard:dev_actual_with_ref.html.twig at line 17
```

help please how I get refernce developer in table CodeUserReference field codereference in twig ?

Comment: I solved
`{% for ref in devs_actual.referencedeveloper %}
        <li>reference{{ ref.codereference }}</li>
    {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `referenceDeveloper` as twig calls the getter methods
So every variable with an "_" get the next character in uppercase instead